# Java/JavaFX: take any types and return

Tags: java, javafx

I am using JavaFX, and I am trying to put a node in center of the pane by doing the math in purpose.

I created a function like this:

```
int toCenterX(Label label){
    return (int) ((width-label.getWidth())/2);
}
```

"width" is a variable I already declared.

Then center it like so:

```
sampleLabel.setLayoutX(toCenterX(sampleLabel));
```

That function works ok, but I want that function to accept not only Label, but other JavaFX classes.

How to take any types of class(node) and use specific methods that class has?

Comment: Since you are fetching width, which is inherited from Region. You can use `int toCenterX(Region region)`. I would personally like you to use `int toCenterX(Control control)`.

Comment: I rather suggest you use Node instead of Control and return a double by using getBoundsInLocal(), getBoundsInParent or getLayoutBounds() depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Control` instead of `Label`. As `Label` inherits from `Control` you can use this function exactly as your old one:

```
int toCenterX(Control control){
    return (int) ((width - control.getWidth()) / 2);
}
```

Comment: Simple and Easy. Thank you sir !